# Change option showCurrentTime

Tags: javascript, vis.js

New to vis.js functionality, and I have set the options as follows:

```
var options =
{
    showMajorLabels: true,
    showMinorLabels: true,
    showCurrentTime: false,
    .....
}
```

I need to allow the user the choose one of showing "showCurrentTime" with default to false. How do I access this dynamically to reset to `true` or `false` based on a variable set when the user selects to show or not.

Comment: `options.showCurrentTime = value;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `setOptions({showCurrentTime: true | false})` to change options on the fly.